# Android ORMLite DatabaseConfigUtil and library project

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I am trying to create a Library project for andorid and I am using ORMLite.

Within my library project I have created `ormlite_config.txt` within the `res/raw folder`. However, when I make a jar of the library project, it gets sealed. So I get the following error.

```
java.alang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity [activityName]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load object config file

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DatabaseTableConfig reading from stream cannot parse line: [random characters]
```

I have thought about using app specific config file stored on device and reading that. But with that is that I cannot get the application context when I run the `DatabaseConfigUtility`.

Has anyone ran into this problem before? Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: have you found a solution in the end?

Answer (score 1):

in the class where you are extending OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper you might be creating a constructor where you would call super class constructor just pass NULL in place of your "R.raw.ormlite_config", the ormlite_config file in my raw folder didn't contain any code , I had the EXACT SAME problem and this solved it for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, in my case I am extending the OrmLiteBaseActivity class and I cannot change that constructor. Any suggestions?

Comment: try having 2 constructors and see what happens ?? bcz even I am not sure how will ORMLite behaves when you extend the base activity